# PHP Selecting and grouping and saving to files

Tags: php, sql, select, pdo, filter

I have a table "org_st" as follow:
[image]

TYPE_ID values are folders names which have to be created
CHKPT_ID values are folders names which have to be created inside relative TYPE_ID
SECT_ID values are text files names which have to be created in relative CHKPT_ID with content ELMT_ID

Ex: Folder(3)/folder(54)/file(4).txt containing value(13). like this:

[image]

and here the relative text file content (13) in the chosen example :

[image]

Is it possible to select and filter within a single PDO statement or I have to pass by multiple SQL queries?

Am really lost in how to handle this question..
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare(" select WHAT?")

Deeply Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM org_st` ? Then loop the result in php and build your folders tree + files + contents

Comment: What do you want to filter by the way?

Comment: hi thank you first. If I select * from org_st then how to group the TYPE_ID by single value to create from them separate folders .. the same for CHKPT_ID which are folders inside TYPE_ID (The screen capture is really showing the wanted result)

Comment: You want to process every lines. In example, for `TYPE_ID = 2`, if you are grouping by `CHKPT_ID` and `SECT_ID` what will be the value you want for `ELMT_ID` ? 8? 10? both? something else? if both, you can't `GROUP BY` and a simple `SELECT * ` will do the job.

Comment: If your question is *"How to write a SQL query that returns a tree ?"* You can't. SQL results are 2D arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Therefore if you can't really suggest a complete vision, then you don'T need to down-vote the question.<br> thx. In fact, I missed some clarity when the answer is just under the nose: Each $row is already a path ready  (put a 'slash' in between the columns and u will see it too..). I'll answer my question next

Comment: I didn't downvoted your question.

Comment: Oh am really sorry!. Thank u and have a nice weekend 'Cid'.

Answer (score -2):

So as I previously commented, I missed some clarity in considering the question: It sounds complicated when it is pretty easy. Every records ($row) is already a 'ready' path!
here scratching on the captured table:
[image]

Now we need just to fire a PDO Select *... here a function which creates a nice folders tree:

```
            public  function fire_all_lists()       
            {   
            try             
            {                       
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("select TYPE_ID,CHKPT_ID,SECT_ID,ELMT_ID FROM org_st");    
            $stmt->execute();
            $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                
            if(!$row) exit('<h1>nothing Bro!</h1>');
            $s= array('en','fr','de','bg','ru','ar') ;
            $ta=count($s);  
            do {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $ta; $i++) {
            $path='lists/'.$s[$i].'/'.$row['TYPE_ID'].'/'.$row['CHKPT_ID'].'/'.$row['SECT_ID'].'.txt';
            $dir='lists/'.$s[$i].'/'.$row['TYPE_ID'].'/'.$row['CHKPT_ID'];
            if(!file_exists($dir)) {
            mkdir($dir, 0755, true);
            }
            file_put_contents($path, '<option>'.$row['ELMT_ID'].'</option>'.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

            }

            } while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); 
            return true;
            $stmt = null;                   
            }                   
            catch(PDOException $e)              
            {                       
            echo $e->getMessage();                  
            }
            }
```

Thank you for your patience. I hope you'll find any interest.